# Link object file to my project Eclipse CDR

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, object-files

I'm working on a project from school, and we were given a .o and a corresponding .h file.
We need to use several functions from the .o file in our .c program.
Just placing it in the same directory doesn't work.
I tried to look for something like this in the project properties, but no good.
I keep getting `../code_files/Search.c:116: undefined reference to 'reportError'`

I'm using Eclipse (Juno) CDT, gcc MinGW under Windows 7

I know it's possible to include .a files, but I couldn't find any indication on how to include a .o file
`#include "ErrorHandle.h"` is included in the main c file.

Anyone knows how to include a .o file to a project?
Thanks!

Comment: Also see [Is it possible to import/run object files in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30086902/608639), [How to link object (.o) file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23396199/608639), [Include object file or assembler file in C Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45338665/608639), [Adding object file to cpp code in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25866628/608639)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this answer:

I tried doing something similar, only I didn't think of the miscellaneous thing
[image]

Comment: How does it know where to search for mtm_ex1.o??

Comment: This worked for me only after I added the full path to the object file: `/home/dd/file.o`. Adding the path `/home/dd` to linker lib search paths did not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially turn the `.o` into a `.a` with `ar cvs library.a object.o`, and then add the .a to your project.