# Adding object file to cpp code in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, object-files

I followed the ways mentioned in 
[Link object file to my project Eclipse CDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810701/link-object-file-to-my-project-eclipse-cdr)

My main function is in cpp code and from that I wish to call a c-function.
So for that I created the object file (.o) from the c-code using

> gcc -c -fpic mycode.c

This gave me a ".o" file which I wanted to link to the cpp code. I created a header file with reference to http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-nonsystem.html

Header file was declared as an extern in my cpp code. The header file contains to function from the c-code, that function was declared as an extern in header file.

After doing this when I do make for my entire project I am getting error as "undefined reference" to that c-function name

Comment: Do the declarations in the header file have the appropriate `extern "C"` or `extern "C" {...}`? Since the code was C, the name mangling will be C, but the C++ compiler will be looking for C++ name mangling.

Comment: This may help with the mix of C and C++ linkage; http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/3747990

Comment: Gave as extern "C" {
#include "foo.h"
} in Cpp code and in separate header file as "extern "C" int foo_main();"

Comment: got the issue resolved my header file looks like #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif                          Also the header i included in my main cpp file as extern "C"{ #include "mycode.h" }... thanku

#ifndef mycode_h__
#define mycode_h__

extern int mycode_main(void);

#endif //mycode_h__

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Comment: Also see [Link object file to my project Eclipse CDR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810701/608639), [Is it possible to import/run object files in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30086902/608639), [How to link object (.o) file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23396199/608639), [Include object file or assembler file in C Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45338665/608639), [Adding object file to cpp code in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25866628/608639)