# Is it possible to import/run object files in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, object-files

Our professor made available object files of a previous assignment that I wasn't able to complete. This previous assignment is required for completing/testing the current assignment. Would it be possible somehow for me to import them into eclipse or somehow make my project work with those object files?

Comment: You will also need header file with functions/classes declarations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask the professor for those later. Do I just drag and drop the object files into the same source folder as my program?

Comment: Also see [Link object file to my project Eclipse CDR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810701/608639), [Is it possible to import/run object files in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30086902/608639), [How to link object (.o) file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23396199/608639), [Include object file or assembler file in C Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45338665/608639), [Adding object file to cpp code in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25866628/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have object file `print_hello.a` and a header `print_hello.h`. To be more precise let's create `print_hello.a`:

**`print_hello.h`**

```
#ifndef __PRINT_HELLO_
#define __PRINT_HELLO_

void print_hello();

#endif /* __PRINT_HELLO__ */
```

**`print_hello.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "print_hello.h"

void print_hello() {
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

Compile it with

```
$ gcc -c print_hello.c -o print_hello.a
```

Now we need to add this to Eclipse. Create a project let's call it `example`. Create a `example.c` in which you will call `print_hello`

```
#include "print_hello.h"

int main() {
    print_hello();
}
```

Now we need to link it to the `print_hello.a`. Right-click on project and choose `Properties`. Go to the `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Miscellaneous`. In the `Other objects` click on add button and choose the path to the `print_hello.a`. Also add path to `.h` file in `GCC C Compiler -> Includes`. Build and run you project, it should output

```
Hello!
```

Comment: This shows how to workaround the problem by converting object to lib; doesn't show how to link with object file.